# Access to QR code coordinate in ZXing on Android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, coordinate

I'm developing a ZXing project in Eclipse:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
        Log.d("test", "button works!");
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


         b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button111);

        }
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
        {
            if (requestCode == 0) 
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");


                    Log.i("xZing", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);
                    // Handle successful scan
                } 
                else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                {
                    // Handle cancel
                    Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
                }
            }
```

I found the finder pattern coordinates are in the `Detector` class (`getTopLeft` and `getTopRight` and `getBottomLeft`) but when I want to access them I'm facee with errors in the code. I don't know how I can access these variables. For example, I define a `public static FinderPattern topLeft1` in the `Detector` class and in the `processFinderPatternInfo` method I add `topLeft1=topLeft`.
After `startActivity` for the result I add:

```
float m1=Detector.topLeft1.x;
 m2=Detector.topLeft1.y;
 b.setText("(x,y)="+m1+","+m2);
```

but when I run the program and click the button to scan: I get:

> unfortunately zxing has stopped

I need 10 reputation to post an image and I can't post logcat image :-(
Can any one help me soon?
Thanks a lot

Comment: what are the errors? can you post the logccat

Comment: if zxing is giving you too many problems you can always use ZBar https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android

Comment: for example i define a "public static FinderPattern topLeft1" in Detector class.and in processFinderPatternInfo method i add topLeft1=topLeft .in main activity after startActivity for result i add float m1=Detector.topLeft1.x;
         m2=Detector.topLeft1.y;
     
           b.setText("(x,y)="+m1+","+m2); but when i run the program and click the button to scan ,an error show:unfortunately zxing has stopped

Comment: @Cob50nm : can you help me? i wrote my error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569819/access-to-qrcode-coordinate-in-zxing-android

Comment: @JoelDean can you help me?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569819/access-to-qrcode-coordinate-in-zxing-android

Comment: I would need the actual logcat print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.I must write OnActivityResult class out of OnCreate Method! That's all!
thank you all.